# Authentication, with html and Javascript only

Tags: javascript, php, authentication

I have done this for browser but now I am developing a hybrid app. I need authentication, I can only use html and JavaScript, since Hybrid app does not support php code. How do I do it such that when app starts it checks, if user is logged on (either via sending a status check request to server, or suggest any other way possible, if php code was possible to use i would check for some session variables and redirect based on that). If user is logged on send inside the app or else present login form. I cannot use Facebook, Google login etc in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Still open, I want to know how do I make sure user is logged on all the time and if not, login page to be displayed. The idea I have so far is to ping the server and check for valid session. Is there any other better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is serverside, you could not have used it "for browser" except on the web server. You would use it for your hybrid app in exactly the same way - on the web server, and not inside your hybrid app. In your hybrid app, you would have an AJAX call, for example, contacting your server for authentication and persistence. It does not need to be PHP, but it does need to be a serverside executable.

You need the server primarily because it makes no sense to even ask if the user is logged in unless there is somewhere they can be logged *into*

Comment: I know php is server side, on a browser I can use a page like index.php(here I can have codes to check current PHPSESSIONID for login status and redirect) on hybrid app I can't. How do I do it on hybrid app.

Comment: You can use AJAX to contact the server.

Comment: yes I can, I am doing it. So based on ajax reply I can do window.location to redirect. But then do I need to make a ajax call again on the next page load to check that user is really logged in and not directly calling the address. For e.g. in php I would have a piece of code on very beginning checking for session/logon status.

Comment: If you're making a single-page app, none of that is important. If you're making a multi-page app, you can use `window.postMessage`, `window.localStorage` or another mechanism from the hybrid app framework you're using to communicate and/or remember the logged-in status between your pages. [More info](http://sdtsui.com/2015/04/15/sharing-your-data-between-WebViews-in-a-hybrid-multi-page-mobile-app/)

Comment: can we call it multi page because there will be only one page if we dont count the login page.

Comment: If you just have one page plus login page, it would probably be easier for you to make it a single page with dialog rather than two pages. But it's really your choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83517/discussion-between-rkrara-and-amadan).